# Exception While Downloading PDF file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am downloading a file in asp.net
Here is the code

```
Response.ContentType = "Application/.pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+extractFileName+".pdf");
Response.TransmitFile(extractFilePath);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

The file is downloading properly but at `Response.End();` it throws following exception:

`{Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}`

Comment: try with . removed from content type example: application/pdf not "Application/.pdf"

Comment: @FrebinFrancis : Still same...

Comment: which browser are you using ? can you please post the value in extractFilename variable ? See this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/afenster/how-to-download-a-file-in-Asp-Net/

Answer (score 0):

The provided message is not an exception, but a message indicating that it cannot show you the error due to optimizations performed by the compiler, and due to the current code location.

Try removing the response.End and see if it will allow you to see the error.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues.

I think the main issue will be that you're using `extractFileName` for both the name that will be used to open/save the file at the browser, and also as the physical name of the file to transmit.  So you are either using a full path for the `content-disposition` when it needs just a filename... or you are not giving a full path for the transmit.

You are also using an incorrect [MIME Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) for the PDF, which should be `application/pdf`

(And you are also include `.pdf` at the end of the `extractFileName`, so I presume the variable doesn't already include the extension?)

If `extractFileName` is the full physical path to the file (including extension), then try replacing...

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+extractFileName+".pdf");
```

with...

```
string contentFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(extractFileName);
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+contentFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

TransmitFile() cannot be used for files outside the directory structure of your website. In that case use another way to write the file to the Response.

Remark:
If the filename contains multiple points (.) or characters like comma (,), some browsers will mess up the filename. Add extra quotes to the filename to avoid problems.

```
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file + "\";");
```